# Unable to send mail from localhost

Tags: php, email, gmail, localhost

I'm not able to send mail from localhost. I tried to change configuration of `php.ini` and `sendmail.ini` as code of both file mentioned below.

This is my mail function from php file.

```
if (mail("exmaplesend@test.pk", "this is subject", "this is testing message", "From:example@gmail.com")) {
    echo 'Email sent successfully!';
} else {
    die('Failure: Email was not sent!');
}
```

and here is the the `php.ini` configuration:

```
SMTP=localhost
SMTP =smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port =587
sendmail_from =example@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

and Sendmail.ini code is here:

```
account Gmail
tls on
tls_certcheck off
host smtp.gmail.com
from [example]@gmail.com
auth on
user [example]@gmail.com
password [**********]

port 587
account default : Gmail
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors when you try this (is your system configured to show you errors?)

Comment: no there is no error.

Comment: Do you have error reporting set to <?php error_reporting(-1); ?> so you're sure to see all errors?

Comment: no i didnt set error report @Niklaus

Comment: is there is anyone point out the main problem because i also used PHPmailer library for that but i m not able send mail. @Niklaus

Comment: If you didn't before, do it now. Add error_reporting(-1); before if (mail(....)) and tell us what it says.

Comment: thanks @Niklaus after getting error my problem is solved.
there is authentication error from gmail account.